# Google App script - why the execution link changed

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, ide

I have a web app using app script from google , I've deploy it before many many times and the execution url which like "https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec" is the same in every time deployed , but suddenly after made some changes on the script , the exec. link have been changed.

I want to know the reason, because it's shouldn't be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new editor:

- Deploy > New deployment will create a new URL every single time.

You want this instead:

- Deploy > Manage deployments: under "Active" at top left, make sure you have the right deployment selected.
- Then click on the pencil icon at the top right to edit this deployment.  Click on the "Version" dropbox and "New version", then "Deploy".  This will update this version with your newest code and keep the same URL as you are not making a new deployment.